# Mouse enter and mouse leave event listeners for stage component in react-konva does not work

Tags: konvajs, react-konva, konvajs-reactjs

Is there mouse enter and mouse leave event listeners for stage component in react-konva? I need to implement collaboration pointer similar like Figma when the users mouse enter, move, and leave the canvas. Tried to use onMouseEnter and onMouseLeave on Stage component, somehow it listens when the cursor touches Rect, Circle, and Arrow components instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `onMouseEnter` and `onMouseLeave` events on the stage itself or for its DOM wrapper.

```js
const App = () => {
  const [entered, setIntered] = React.useState(false);
  return (
    <Stage
      width={window.innerWidth / 2}
      height={window.innerHeight / 2}
      onMouseEnter={() => {
        setIntered(true);
      }}
      onMouseLeave={() => {
        setIntered(false);
      }}
      style={{
        border: "1px solid red",
        margin: "5px",
        display: "inline-block"
      }}
    >
      <Layer>
        <Text
          text={`Mouse is ${entered ? "inside" : "outside"} of canvas.`}
          fontSize={15}
        />
      </Layer>
    </Stage>
  );
};
```

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-konva-mouseevent-event-us0w8?file=/src/index.js

Comment: @lvrton - just FYI Konva tutorial docs say stage does not have its own events. I concur that it does now. Docs out of date at https://konvajs.org/docs/events/Stage_Events.html.

Comment: @VanquishedWombat probably I need to find better words for it.

Comment: @lavrton I used react-konva 16.8 before when it didn't work. Just now I updated to 16.13 also konva to 6.0.0 and it works properly, thanks!